# Is it possible to call Jquery methods from typescript?

Tags: jquery, typescript, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use the method which is present in jquery plugin from typescript.
I have included that plugins in index.html. Can anyone help me to invoke the plugin method from typescript.

Source :

```
//plugin
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
//import * from '../../../assets/js/query-builder/query-builder"
declare var $ : any;

@Component({
    selector: 'rule',
    template: ` <script src="assets/js/query-builder/query-builder.js"></script><div  id="Query"> <query-builder class="margin30" [data]="query" [config]="config"></query-builder>
    <div class="margin30">
      <textarea >{{query | json}}</textarea>
      <button md-raised-button type="button" color="primary" name="and" (click)="OnANDClick()">AND</button>
    </div> </div>`
})

export class RSComponent{

   //Builded query codes

    OnANDClick(){

      var query = $("#Query");
      //$.getSQL("string", '\n', this.query)
     //var resSql = query.getSQL("string", '\n', this.query);
     //var sqlParsed = resSql.sql;
    // console.log(sqlParsed);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide some source code, to understand with is your epectation

Comment: TypeScript transpiles to plain JavaScript, so it should not be any different than invoking the plugin from JavaScript.

Comment: For checking, i have coded in template by using script, but already i have referred in index.html

Comment: Maybe that article can help: https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/typescript-integrate-jquery-plugin-in-your-project-e28c6887d8dc